# Why Minimum request body data rate configuration is needed?

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

In Asp.Net Core there is `Minimum request body data rate` configuration. Which says:

> Kestrel checks every second if data is arriving at the specified rate
> in bytes/second. If the rate drops below the minimum, the connection
> is timed out. The grace period is the amount of time Kestrel allows
> the client to increase its send rate up to the minimum. The rate isn't
> checked during that time. The grace period helps avoid dropping
> connections that are initially sending data at a slow rate because of
> TCP slow-start.
>
> The default minimum rate is 240 bytes/second with a 5-second grace
> period.

What's the purpose of this slow requests filtering? Why would it would 'bad' to set minimum rate to 0? And does slow request happen because of client's slow Internet connection?

Comment: I don't know for certain but assume this is to free up the resources allocated per connection. Without this every request to your server would remain an open connection unless specifically instructed to close from the client.

Answer (score 2):

Security reasons. Read up on slow loris attacks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)